# Eclipse Team Synchronization - Difference between Workspace and Java Workspace (SVN)

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I want to know the difference between this 2 options.
What will happen if I select: both/only Workspace/only Java Workspace?

[image: Eclipse Synchronize Selection]

Answer (score 0):

**Workspace** looks at all projects in your workspace. It doesn't matter if it is a project with Java source code or not.

**Java Workspace** only looks at projects that really have java source code, and this project usually have a *.project* file which inludes a definition for the *org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder* and the *org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature*.

For example you have a maven assembly project the .project file would look like this and will occur in the **Workspace** but not in the **Java Workspace** list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>solr-assembly</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```